# what data mining algorithm can be applied to determine reorder point of inventory items?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an EOQ model for inventory management in php. I have to decide the reorder point for inventory items or when to reorder a particular item and in how much bulk? for this i need some data mining algorithm that could serve this purpose and also can possibly be implemented in php.. your answers would be appreciated

Comment: have a column in your database called in stock when you order 5 set it to 5, every time one is sold mark it as -1.  once it hits 2 items in stock order more.  Don't let the system automatically adjust order quantities for you its massively dangerous unless you have the resources to put behind it.  Just give it a fixed quantity and let it auto re-order on that quantity.  So if you order in 1k lots reorder at 100 in stock etc.

Comment: This is what I have already done but that seems to me quite static. i need some algorithm that would decide this reorder point dynamically

Comment: basically you can do an average order per week so take the total number of items per week add them all up and divide by number of weeks gets your average so if you get to a stock point below that order auto re-order the average x 4 to buy say a months stock.  now this is its most basic form and doesn't take into effect spikes or troughs but unless you're working on a very large e-comm system it'll be enough.